# Keep VideoView (Android ICS+) playing when switching tab

Tags: android, android-videoview

Phone only with Android 4.0+ and no other third party libraries.

Application uses Navigation Tab of the ActionBar. One of the tab contains the stock VideoView control from ICS streaming live video from a source.  I want to have the VideoView keep playing when user switch tabs to view information (call it InformationView).

On a tablet, I don't have this issue because the screen size is bigger and I make VideoView always on screen.
On a phone, screen is smaller therefore tab must be used.

I understand that VideoView probably depends on a visible surface in order to draw the video frame. When user switch tabs, the surface isn't available to VideoView therefore it automatically stops.

I can probably work around this by using a big scrollview that contains both InformationView and VideoView.

Is there any way to force it keep playing (maybe by drawing to an invisible surface)  or is there a third party library that mimic the 'tab' behavior by using a giant scrollview so I don't have to write more code?

Note this isn't the same as multiple VideoViews problem which described here: [One videoview blocked by another videoview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5681830/one-videoview-blocked-by-another-videoview)

Answer (score 0):

OK the solution is to hide the fragment that contains the VideoView when switching tabs, hence there is always a 'surface' video view can draw to.

Answer (score 0):

You can custom VideoView same default but that's different you should control holder surface, oncreatSurface, onchangeSurface().

Answer (score 0):

A better implementation of this concept would be not to use the stock `VideoView` widget, which is really just a marrying together of a `SurfaceView` and a `MediaPlayer`, but to divorce these two and use them individually.  If your application controls the `MediaPlayer` directly, is can continue to play the audio track even after the surface disappears.

Making your `Activity` or `Fragment` one of the `SurfaceHolder.Callback` instances attached to the `SurfaceView` will allow you to know when the surface is or is not available for drawing.  The `MediaPlayer` methods `setDisplay()` and `setSurface()` would be then used in your application to attach and detach the video surface when it becomes available in the view hierarchy per that callback.

You may also find the source of `VideoView` helpful ([link](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/widget/VideoView.java)) in coming up with your own implementation that accomplishes a similar goal.